# How to return one activity back with actionbarActivity back button?

Tags: android, json, android-actionbaractivity

I made a app with multiple activities. And there are some problem that I cannot solve on my own.

For example, I have 4 activities named "MainMenu","Secondpage","Thirdpage", and a "Fourthpage". From The MainMenu , I pass a id with putExtras() to pass over to the Secondpage so that the Secondpage gets the id and sets it into a url to get the json data from the web. After the "Secondpage" gets the json data,it will display it in a listView. The user will now be able to click the listView to mover over to the "Thirdpage" that contains the id and the data passed from the "Secondpage". Now the problem is that from this "Thirdpage", I want to go back to the "Secondpage" but I cannot find a way to do this. 
I've set the manifest file like the follwing, however, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.  Or should I set something up in the ActionbarActivity class?

Sample

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Secondpage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first_time_user"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Thirdpage"
            android:label="@string/title"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.me.Secondpage" />
```

Comment: When you press back button in Thirdpage, what happened?

Comment: It goes to the MainMenu. It skips the other activites and hops over.

Comment: What's your code of starting ThirdActivity? Show me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say

> I want to go back to the "Secondpage"

you mean like if you have pressed the back button?
If so, you can just call `finish();` in your third activity to do that.

**EDIT:**

In your third Activity, add

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

or, if you are using the support library

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in your `onCreate(Bundle b)` method

And

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

elsewhere in your class.

Comment: Well,  I want to go back one activity back, but how will I set the finish() for the  ActionBarActivity's backbutton  (Not the default onBackpressed)?

Comment: I've tried  your sample and set the getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); within the onCreate() , however, when I set the getActionBar(),  The app crashes. I'm currently using    minSdkVersion 19 ,targetSdkVersion 22.

Answer (score 1):

Just call

```
onBackPressed()
```

if you want to have a behaviour like the user uses his back button. You should return to the SecondPage without any problems.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use the back button in the action bar [check this one out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292691/using-support-action-bar-home-enabled/28054105#28054105)

Comment: I already have it , and the problem is that I want to use the ActionBarActivitys back button. And in order to use it I'm forced to set the  meta-data in the manifest file. Im finding the solution to use the onBackpressed in the Actionbars back button.

Comment: I provided a link which shows you how to show the back button in the action bar and use it to go back to your previous activity.

Comment: Thank you. Now I thought the problem was getting solved and now I have to deal with an unexpected app crash when I set the getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); within the onCreate() .

Comment: Can you please post the error log when your app crashes ?
Are you using the support library ? It should be getSupportActionBar() if you do so.

Comment: Everything is in perfect condition since I've used getSupportActionBar()!